# Why is my function executing twice?

Tags: python

A function in my code repeats twice. In the chooseName() function, it asks the question, and once you answer, it repeats the question and then moves on with the rest of the code. Why does it do this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print("Hello, there! Glad to meet you!")
    print("Welcome to the world of Pokémon!")
    print("My name is Maple.")
    print("People affectionately refer to me as the Pokémon Professor.")
    print("This world is inhabited far and wide by creatures called Pokémon.")
    print("For some people, Pokémon are pets.")
    print("Others use them for battling.")
    print("As for myself, I study Pokémon as a profession.")
    print("But first, tell me a little about yourself.")

def chooseGender():
    gender = ""
    while gender != "boy" and gender != "girl":
        gender = raw_input("Now tell me. Are you a boy? Or are you a girl? ")

    return gender

def chooseName():
    name = ""
    name = raw_input("Let's begin with your name. What is it? ")

    return name

def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    answer = ""
    while answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
        answer = raw_input("Right... So your name is " + str(name) + "? (yes or no) ")

    return answer
    if answer == "yes":
        print("I have a grandson.")
        print("He's been your rival since you both were babies.")
        print("...Erm, what was his name now?")
        # raw_input for their name
        print("...Er, was it") #raw_input for name
        # Let user pick yes or no
        # If yes, move on
        # If no, ask name again
        print("That's right! I remember now! His name is") #raw_input for name
        print("your name!") # raw_input for name
        print("Your very own Pokémon legend is about to unfold!")
        print("A world of dreams and adventures with Pokémon awaits! Let's go!")
    if answer == "no":
        chooseName()

displayIntro()
chooseGender()
chooseName()
nameConfirmation()
```

I apologize for not posting the rest of the code sooner.
This is the output.

```
Let's begin with your name. What is it? Raven
Let's begin with your name. What is it? Raven
```

Comment: There is nowhere in this code that chooseName is called. Provide a complete program.

Comment: Are you calling `chooseName()` twice somewhere?

Comment: Can provide complete program?

Comment: You have just provided functions. Can you provide piece of code that executes these functions?

Comment: I called displayIntro(), then chooseGender(), then chooseName() at the end of the program. That's the only time I call them. The reason why I didn't include the rest of the program was because it didn't involve chooseName() at all, and it wasn't complete.

Comment: You don't seem to understand... Nobody can tell you what the issue is based on what you've provided. You don't need to include everything. Just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I edited the rest of the code in.

Comment: you called chooseName() twice one in ```nameConfirmation()``` and before that same function.

Comment: @ManojJadhav Well, it started executing twice before I started working on nameConfirmation() at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `chooseName( )` call below `chooseGender( )` as it has already been called in `nameConfirmation( )` definition. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As `chooseName()` is getting called twice first below call of `chooseGender()` and second inside `nameConfirmation()` so that's the reason it is getting executed twice. As a fixed you can comment or remove `chooseName()` which is below `chooseGender()` as shown.

```
displayIntro()
chooseGender()
# chooseName()
nameConfirmation()
```

So updated code will be as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print("Hello, there! Glad to meet you!")
    print("Welcome to the world of Pokémon!")
    print("My name is Maple.")
    print("People affectionately refer to me as the Pokémon Professor.")
    print("This world is inhabited far and wide by creatures called Pokémon.")
    print("For some people, Pokémon are pets.")
    print("Others use them for battling.")
    print("As for myself, I study Pokémon as a profession.")
    print("But first, tell me a little about yourself.")

def chooseGender():
    gender = ""
    while gender != "boy" and gender != "girl":
        gender = raw_input("Now tell me. Are you a boy? Or are you a girl? ")

    return gender

def chooseName():
    name = ""
    name = raw_input("Let's begin with your name. What is it? ")

    return name

def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    answer = ""
    while answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
        answer = raw_input("Right... So your name is " + str(name) + "? (yes or no) ")

    return answer
    if answer == "yes":
        print("I have a grandson.")
        print("He's been your rival since you both were babies.")
        print("...Erm, what was his name now?")
        # raw_input for their name
        print("...Er, was it") #raw_input for name
        # Let user pick yes or no
        # If yes, move on
        # If no, ask name again
        print("That's right! I remember now! His name is") #raw_input for name
        print("your name!") # raw_input for name
        print("Your very own Pokémon legend is about to unfold!")
        print("A world of dreams and adventures with Pokémon awaits! Let's go!")
    if answer == "no":
        chooseName()

displayIntro()
chooseGender()
# chooseName()
nameConfirmation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modification in your code , Here is updated code:

> First edit :

You are calling chooseName() two times ,

> Second edit :

**You are returning before main logic of your program.**

Here

```
def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    answer = ""
    while answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
        answer = raw_input("Right... So your name is " + str(name) + "? (yes or no) ")

    return answer
```

You should keep in mind that function is not going to execute anything after you return from it so your code from `if answer == "yes":` is not going to execute even if user type `yes` or `no`

So return it at the last of the program or if you want to return at the same place then use print there instead of 'return'.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print("Hello, there! Glad to meet you!")
    print("Welcome to the world of Pokémon!")
    print("My name is Maple.")
    print("People affectionately refer to me as the Pokémon Professor.")
    print("This world is inhabited far and wide by creatures called Pokémon.")
    print("For some people, Pokémon are pets.")
    print("Others use them for battling.")
    print("As for myself, I study Pokémon as a profession.")
    print("But first, tell me a little about yourself.")

def chooseGender():
    gender = ""
    while gender != "boy" and gender != "girl":
        gender = input("Now tell me. Are you a boy? Or are you a girl? ")

    return gender

def chooseName():
    name = ""
    name = input("Let's begin with your name. What is it? ")

    return name

def nameConfirmation():
    name = chooseName()
    answer = ""
    while answer != "yes" and answer != "no":
        answer = input("Right... So your name is " + str(name) + "? (yes or no) ")


    if answer == "yes":
        print("I have a grandson.")
        print("He's been your rival since you both were babies.")
        print("...Erm, what was his name now?")
        # raw_input for their name
        print("...Er, was it") #raw_input for name
        # Let user pick yes or no
        # If yes, move on
        # If no, ask name again
        print("That's right! I remember now! His name is") #raw_input for name
        print("your name!") # raw_input for name
        print("Your very own Pokémon legend is about to unfold!")
        print("A world of dreams and adventures with Pokémon awaits! Let's go!")
    if answer == "no":
        chooseName()
    return answer

displayIntro()
chooseGender()
nameConfirmation()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the function `choseName()` and then right after you call `nameConfiguration()` wich starts by calling `choseName()`, that's why it is called twice. You can simply remove the `choseName()` before `nameConfiguration()`.